# Lookup of multiple cell to calculate amount from multiple cells

Tags: excel, if-statement, indexing, formula, vlookup

I am trying to find a formula for below

I have a premium amount which is any number
these premium amount are in different currencies
I have a Rate of Exchange tab that converts all currencies to all currencies. e.g: USD to GBP or EUR to USD or GBP to EUR

Now I want to convert every premium into 1. USD and 2 GBP. any help will be greatly appreciated.

[Actual Excel spreadhseet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHiNX.png)

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is just to use a `vlookup()` to get the conversion, then multiply that by the number.  Here's what I did, you will have to adjust of course based on where your exchange rates are, and how they're laid out, but this should work:

[image]

And then for the Sterling column, I'd switch the vlookup to search `$I$2:$J$8`.